# Usar LIMIT em uma DataTable

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Utilizo uma `DataTable` para exibir alguns registros, sempre que eu entro em uma determinada página, dou <kbd>F5</kbd>, a tabela "demora" para se "compactar", pois a página está carregando *todos os registros* do meu `select`.

Creio que a forma ideal seria fazer a página carregar uma quantidade de registros por página selecionada (paginação da table), porém, não sei como fazer isso.

Se eu apenas colocar:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contas LIMIT 1, 10";
```

Só irá exibir 10 registros do meu banco obviamente.

Eu usei `"pageLength"` no script, mas ele também não impede da página carregar todos os registros.

Então, como posso estar usar `LIMIT` ou outra ferramenta para "impedir" a página de carregar todos os registros de uma vez?

Script que estou utilizando:

```js
// LISTAGEM SCROLL
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dtHorizontalExample').DataTable({
"scrollX": true,
"pageLength": 10 
});
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
```

Meu SQL:

```php
$sql = "SELECT contas.* , estabelecimento_detalhes.* FROM contas, estabelecimento_detalhes WHERE contas.estabelecimento = estabelecimento_detalhes.estabelecimento AND contas.categoria != 'EMPRESA-X'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para você fazer isso você precisa usar jQuery Datatable Server-Side
vou fazer um exemplo para você ter uma ideia melhor.

Com base em uma tabela, ficaria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/home/loaddataserver",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype":"json"
                },
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "filter": false,
                "orderMulti": false,
                "paging": true,
                "info":false,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id", "name": "id", "autoWidth": true },                       //index 0
                    { "data": "nome", "name": "nome", "autoWidth": true },                   //index 1
                    { "data": "fornecedor.nome", "name":"fornecedor.nome", "autoWidth": true },//index 2
                    { "data": "categoria.nome", "name":"categoria.nome", "autoWidth": true },//index 3
                    { "data": "precoDeCusto", "name":"precoDeCusto", "autoWidth": true },  //index 4
                    { "data": "precoDeVenda", "name": "precoDeVenda", "autoWidth": true }, //index 5
                    { "data": "medicao", "name":"medicao", "autoWidth": true }, //index 6
                    { "data": "status", "name":"status", "autoWidth": true } //index 7
                ],
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Visualizando _MENU_ Registros por página",
                    "zeroRecords": "Não existe registros para visualização",
                    "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "Página Anterior",
                        "next": "Próxima página"
                    }
                }
            });


    </script>
```

Na sua controller você precisa fazer o método que vai enviar e receber os dados usando json, segue um exemplo feito no asp.net core:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult loaddataserver()
        {

            var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();

            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns"] + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]".FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();

            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int totalRecords = 0;

          //  var v = ( database.Produtos.Include(p => p.Categoria).Include(p => p.Fornecedor).Where(p => p.Id <= 35));
            var v = (database.Produtos.Include(p => p.Categoria).Include(p => p.Fornecedor));

            //SORT
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
            {
             //   v = v.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
            }

            totalRecords = v.Count();
            var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = data });

        }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, só tenho uma duvida na segunda parte, aonde devo colocar ela? no arquivo mencionando na `URL`?

Comment: A segunda parte e o código do controller, você está usando MVC no php ? veja no link  "url": "/home/loaddataserver", está enviando um post para uma controller, se a resposta ajudou, não esquece de marca como solução para ajudar outras pessoas também

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, sou bem leigo/novo nesse rumo, não possuo esse diretório e nem algo parecido, aparentemente não uso "MVC" então... mas se eu criar um arquivo, mencionar na url e colocar a segunda parte, funcionara?

Comment: Sim, vai funcionar, desque esteja trazendo os dados corretos, porque o que postei e um exemplo, você tem que ajustar para os dados da sua tabela, basta seguir como modelo

Comment: Sim sim, vou tentar aqui e ja te retorno... estou usando o seu código e um site que explica bem também [site](https://makitweb.com/datatables-ajax-pagination-with-search-and-sort-php/), desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Bom, até agora nada... não é exibido nada, eu provavelmente estou errando em algo...

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, CTJR_Tecnico, também sou novo por aqui, mas se eu entendi direito, nas minhas páginas, quando quero limitar o tanto de registro que quero mostrar no DataTable, eu coloco está linha:
iDisplayLength: 10,

Vou colocar meu código, espero que te ajude.

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $('#tabela').DataTable( {
                  initComplete: function () {
                    this.api().columns().every( function () {
                      var column = this;
                      var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                          );

                          column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                        } );

                      column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                            } );
                        } );
                    },

                    dom: 'lBfrtip',

                    buttons: [
                        'excelHtml5',
                    {
                            extend: 'colvis',
                            collectionLayout: 'fixed four-column',
                            text: 'Visualização'
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'colvisGroup',
                            text: 'Mostrar tudo',
                            show: ':hidden'
                        }
                    ],

                    iDisplayLength: 10, //está linha fará com que traga até 10 registros na minha página.
                    bPaginate: true, //coloco verdadeiro para ter paginação.
                    bInfo: true, //coloco verdadeiro também para trazer as informações das páginas.
                                    bFilter: true,
                                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                                    "bRetrieve": true,
                                    "bDestroy": true,
                                    "oLanguage": {
                                        "sEmptyTable":     "Nenhum registro encontrado na tabela",
                                        "sInfo": "Mostrar _START_ até _END_ do _TOTAL_ registros",
                                        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrar 0 até 0 de 0 Registros",
                                        "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrar de _MAX_ total registros)",
                                        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                                        "sInfoThousands":  ".",
                                        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                                        "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                                        "sProcessing":     "Processando...",
                                        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                                        "sSearch": "Pesquisar: ",
                                        "oPaginate": {
                                            "sNext": "Proximo",
                                            "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                                            "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                                            "sLast":"Ultimo"
                                        },
                                        "oAria": {
                                            "sSortAscending":  ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                                            "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                                        }
                                    },

                });
            } );
        </script>
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela respostas, não sei se "limitar" é a palavra certa, só quero que a `DataTable` **não carregue todos os registros de uma vez**, e sim, que carregue de 10 em 10... eu sei como exibir 5 em 5, 10 em 10, e etc...

Comment: Intendi, é isso mesmo, bom eu pelo menos colocando:                  iDisplayLength: 10, bPaginate: true,    vou trazer só 10 registros na minha páginha, aí eu passo para a próxima e vejo os próximos 10 e assim por diante, mas tenho todos os registros do meu select já preparados para mostrar.

Comment: Vou testar, qualquer duvida eu te falo, obrigado!

Comment: Bom, adicionei ao meu script, e aparentemente não funcionou... a página ainda "demora"... `<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tabela').DataTable({
"scrollX": true,
"iDisplayLength": 10, //está linha fará com que traga até 10 registros na minha página.
});
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
</script>         
`

Comment: Ela demora para carregar mas trás os 10 registros na primeira página, ou ela demora para carregar e trás e trás mais 10 registros na página?

Comment: Ela demora pra carregar, por que "já carregou todos os registros" (aperta CTRL + U, na sua tabela e confere se já não tem todos os registros...), e não é "demorar" a palavra certa, mas a tabela meio que "buga" e depois volta...

Comment: Fiz o teste apertando CTRL + U e minha tabela carregou todos os dados, mas também não são muitos, são só apenas 140, acho que por isso não travou, não sei o que pode ser no seu caso, mas faça alguns testes, tente trazer menos registros, ou menos dados, ao invés de * from, traga menos informações, ou se você está rodando em um servidor local na sua máquina ou em um domínio, isso pode ter influência também. Faça estes teste para ver se consegue.

Comment: A tabela não trava como já falei, ela "buga" no começo e depois volta. O servidor é online, e o `SELECT` está o máximo simplificado... obrigado por tentar ajudar!